# Promo rules not applied when using custom attribute in condition

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, coupon-codes

**In magento2,** I'm using the product custom attribute and setting a condition in promo rule.

When the product is in a cart and if I use that promo rule, it's showing the coupon is not valid.
Somebody suggest an idea.